# How to translate a Structural Equation Model (SEM) or a Graphical Causal Model to the Rubin Potential Outcomes Framework?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, causality, graphical-model, observational-study

I understand that there is sort of a disagreement in statistics and econometrics about the usage of Structural Equation Models vs. Graphical Causal Models vs. Potential Outcomes Model. It has been proved by Pearl that these models in general are the same and that one theorem proved in each implies a theorem proved in another model.

However, I was wondering if there was any specific resources for translation between a Graphical Causal Model displayed through a Structural Equation Model and the Potential Outcomes Framework. It seems that there is but one "proof", and that is given by Pearl, albeit he uses the "do" operator notation and his proof is more of proving a separate theorem that then indirectly shows both models are the same.

I was wondering if there was a direct way of going between a Structural Equation Model and a Potential Outcomes framework. Thanks.

Comment: You may find [Valeri and VanderWeele (2013)](http://www-psychology.concordia.ca/fac/kline/sem/QICSS2/valeri2013.pdf) helpful.

Comment: Thomas Richardson and Jamie Robins have an approach called "Single World Intervention Graphs" (SWIGs). See, for example, [these slides](http://people.tuebingen.mpg.de/p/causality-perspect/slides/Thomas_swig.pdf).

Comment: @LizzieSilver Thanks for the slides. While they give the general notion, it doesn't appear to give a general way of translating from a structural equation model. Specifically, is there a way to translate equation $(1)$ in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06565v1.pdf in your opinion? The note underneath states it can be done.